# How can I store multiple object of same key-value pair in Redis Cache?

Tags: node.js, redis, redis-cache

I want to store multiple object of same Key_Value in Redis cache using node js?
Append, hset or hmset.
Can someone give and example with proper function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REDIS HASHES](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes) instead. You can store the key-value pair in hashes by following:

```
HSET `UNIQUE_KEY` `key` `value`
```

eg.

```
HSET 123_foo id_123 '{"name": "foo", "age": 20}'
```